# Correct translation

Tags: translation

I am having trouble translating the following sentence:

> スーザンは一人で淋しがっています。

I can't determine whether it means:

1. Susan feels lonely by herself.
2. Only Susan is feeling lonely.
3. Susan seems lonely by herself.

From my understanding of ~がっています is that it means "shows signs of~"

So the sentence in my mind should mean "Susan seems lonely by herself."

Comment: You are correct. #1 would not be said in Japanese (one does not outright state what others' internal state is), and #2 would be expressed using だけ or しか…ない. However, since #1 is as natural in English as #3, both are appropriate translations into English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's go by exclusion.

We can pretty much exclude 2.: it implies a comparison among other people, and there is nothing here that seems to suggest that (だけ、しか。。ない, etc). Unless, maybe I should add, in this case the は is used as contrast particle, which implies that the speaker "knows" that she feels lonely by herself (but others don't).

Number 1 and 3 are pretty similar in English, and could both work in this case. 淋しがる is an intransitive verb meaning "to miss someone / to feel lonely".

The -がる construction with いーadjectives turns the word from an adjective to a verb meaning feeling like or looking like (as you say) that adjective. In this case, it just means "feeling lonely". For more about -garu, see [here](https://selftaughtjapanese.com/2014/04/21/japanese-suffix-%E3%83%BC%E3%81%8C%E3%82%8B-garu/) for example. There is actually also an example very similar to yours.

So to recap, *Susan feels lonely by herself*, seems the most appropriate translation to me.

However, I would like to point out also another option.

Do you know that two sentences can be connected by the "pre-masu" form of a verb? See [this question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/48667/why-this-verb-isnt-in-the-dictionary-form/48671#48671) for example. Well it works in the same way with です --＞ で.

Hence, in this case, the sentence:

> スーザンは一人で淋しがっています。

could also be:

*Susan is alone and (because of that) she feels lonely.*

**PS**. I also asked a native speaker about this sentence and she said it could be both, either 1. or my last example.

Comment: This answer looks perfect. I also interpret it as "Susan is alone and (because of that) she feels lonely.", and option 1 in the original question is the closest to this interpretation.

Comment: @norio thanks.. still someone down-voted it for some reason..

Comment: Your answer couldn't be more perfect. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

> スーザンは一人で淋しがっています。

I think you can apply the sentence #1, #2, #3. I analyze the sentence as the following

1. (**I heard**) Susan feels lonely by herself.
2. (**I know**) Only Susan is feeling lonely (by her complaining about her environment).
3. (**Judging from her appearance**)Susan seems lonely by herself.

I think these 3 sentence describes she is showing the sign of ~.